# how to bound latitude and longitude in android?

Tags: android, google-api

how to bound latitude and longitude while calling for google [place autocomplete](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/) using url in android. I tried `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` but it shows

```
cannot resolve symbol PlaceAutocompleteFragment.
```

Comment: Are you not compiling with `PlayServices` in your build gradle? I would assume it has dependencies...

Comment: I compile using this 'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PlaceAutocompleteFragment was introduced in play services version 8.4.0 so use 
    `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'`

in your build.gradle file to use the PlaceAutocompleteFragment widget